# Out of memory when launching liquibase command "dropAllForeignKey"

Tags: java, out-of-memory, sybase, liquibase

I'm running the liquibase command "dropAllForeignKey" on Sybase database with more than 12000 tables and more than 380000 columns. I'm getting an out of memory exception since liquibase code is trying to query all the columns in the data base.

The JVM is launched with : -Xms64M -Xmx512M (if I increase it to 5GO it'll work but I don't see why we have to query all the columns in the data base)

The script I'm using :

```
<dropAllForeignKeyConstraints baseTableName="Table_Name"/>
```

When I checked liquibase code I found that:

1. In DropAllForeignKeyConstraintsChange: we create a snapshot for the table mentioned in the xml

   Table target = SnapshotGeneratorFactory.getInstance().createSnapshot(
                   new Table(catalogAndSchema.getCatalogName(), catalogAndSchema.getSchemaName(),
                           database.correctObjectName(getBaseTableName(), Table.class))
                   , database);
2. In JdbcDatabaseSnapshot: when we call getColumns, we call the bulkFetchQuery() instead of fastFetchQuery() because the table is neither "DatabaseChangeLogTableName" nor "DatabaseChangeLogLockTableName". In this case, the bulkFetchQuery does not filter on the table given in the dropAllForeignKey xml. Instead, it uses SQL_FILTER_MATCH_ALL, so it'll retrieve all the columns in the database. (It already takes time to query all the columns)
3. In ColumnMapRowMapper: for each table, we create a LinkedHashMap with size aqual to the number of columns. And here, I'm getting the out of memory

Is it normal that we query all the column when dropping all the foreign keys for a given table? If it's the case, why we need to do it and is there a solution for my problem without increasing the size of the JVM?

PS: There is another command called dropForeignKey to drop the forign key but it needs the name of the foreign key as an input and I don't have it. In fact, I can find the name of the foreign key for a given data base, but I'm running this command on different data bases and the name of the foreign key changes from one to another and I need to have a generic liquibase change. So, I can't use dropForeignKey and I need to use dropAllForeignKey.

Here the stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.newNode(LinkedHashMap.java:256)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:637)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:607)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.ColumnMapRowMapper.mapRow(ColumnMapRowMapper.java:35)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:72)
at liquibase.snapshot.ResultSetCache$ResultSetExtractor.extract(ResultSetCache.java:297)
at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot$CachingDatabaseMetaData$3.extract(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:774)
at liquibase.snapshot.ResultSetCache$ResultSetExtractor.extract(ResultSetCache.java:288)
at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot$CachingDatabaseMetaData$3.bulkFetchQuery(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:606)
at liquibase.snapshot.ResultSetCache$SingleResultSetExtractor.bulkFetch(ResultSetCache.java:353)
at liquibase.snapshot.ResultSetCache.get(ResultSetCache.java:59)
at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot$CachingDatabaseMetaData.getColumns(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:539)
at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.ColumnSnapshotGenerator.addTo(ColumnSnapshotGenerator.java:106)
at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:79)
at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:49)
at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.include(DatabaseSnapshot.java:286)
at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.init(DatabaseSnapshot.java:102)
at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.<init>(DatabaseSnapshot.java:59)
at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.<init>(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:38)
at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:217)
at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:246)
at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:230)
at liquibase.change.core.DropAllForeignKeyConstraintsChange.generateChildren(DropAllForeignKeyConstraintsChange.java:90)
at liquibase.change.core.DropAllForeignKeyConstraintsChange.generateStatements(DropAllForeignKeyConstraintsChange.java:59)
```

Comment: You'll have to ask the people who wrote Liquibase for that. You could even submit a patch if you think this is important and you want to/can fix it. But since you can get it to run by increasing the memory, what's your actual question here?

Comment: I real life I can't increase the jvm memory to 5GO just because this command need that. I'm using a specific JVM for this and it can't have more than 512M. For me, it shouldn't take more. I increased it only for test to make sure that this was the real issue. What do you mean by submitting a path? how can I do that? Thanks

Comment: If you feel that doing that operation for 12000 tables and 380000 columns should be doable with `512M`, then your issue is with the developers of Liquibase. Submit a bug report / feature request to them, if you can't write a patch yourself. There's not much we can do for you, as it's not your code.

Comment: it is possible they have not implemented garbage-collection properly, which is why you're running out of memory. Try running this command in separate command calls with clustered table names, like "where table_name between  'A' and 'J, etc'"